# Excel VBA click website button with no name or ID that uses JSON

Tags: vba, internet-explorer, web-scraping, automation

I am using excel VBA to open this website:
[Legal and General](https://fundcentres.lgim.com/uk/workplace-employee/fund-centre/#Product=WorkSave-Pension-Plan-(generation-3)), 
Then it needs to click the "Fund prices and charges" button.

Inspecting the web page with chrome, I can see this button has the following code:

`<div class=" selected tab" tabindex ="0" role="button" aria-pressed="true">...</div>`

The HTML 'view source' suggests a script type="application/JSON"

I'm very confused by all of this. Does anyone know how I can select this button? I have this section of code so far:

```
 Set HTMLDoc = .document

Set objElement = HTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName("Select - Tab - Fund prices and charges")(0)

    objElement.Click

.Quit
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Regards

Dave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If only interested in that one tab I would first grab the parent element (div), which houses all the tabs, by its classname using a css class selector. I would then use a child combinator in combination with nth-child() selector to grab the second child div by its classname:

```
.querySelector(".table-view__tabs > div:nth-child(2)").Click 'Select tab direct
```

If potentially interested in all 3 tabs:

I would first grab the parent element (div), which houses all the tabs, by its classname using a css class selector. I would then use a child combinator to grab the child divs (which are the tabs) by their classnames. I would index into the returned nodeList to click the required tab:

```
Set tabs = .querySelectorAll(".table-view__tabs > div") 'select all tabs then index in for tab of choice
tabs.Item(1).Click
```

---

**VBA:**

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub ClickButton()

    Dim ie As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer

    Set ie = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer

    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate2 "https://fundcentres.lgim.com/uk/workplace-employee/fund-centre/#Product=WorkSave-Pension-Plan-(generation-3)"

        While .Busy Or .ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend

        With .Document

            .querySelector(".table-view__tabs > div:nth-child(2)").Click 'Select tab direct

            Stop  'Delete me later

            Dim tabs As Object

            Set tabs = .querySelectorAll(".table-view__tabs > div") 'select all tabs then index in for tab of choice
            tabs.Item(1).Click                   '0 based so first tab is 0, second is 1 etc

            Stop                                 'Delete me later

        End With

        Stop                                     '<==Delete me later
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

---

**Reading:**

1. [CSS selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors)
2. [Child combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator)
3. [Class selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors)
4. [:nth-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child)
5. [document.querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectoraLL)
6. [document.querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

---

**References (VBE>Tools>References):**

1. Microsoft Internet Controls

Comment: QHarr, that worked a treat! Many thanks for your time on this! All the best, Dave.