# Excel VBA click website button with CSS selector on JSON

Tags: css, css-selectors

I had a similar query excellently answered by QHarr last year, however I have a  new problem, but can't quite figure out how to do this.

I use excel VBA to open this website:
[Legal and General - Fund Centre](https://www.legalandgeneral.com/investments/funds/prices-and-reports/daily-fund-prices/)

I then want to click through each tab in turn:
Index funds --> Actively managed --> Fixed Income --> etc...
Grabbing data each time, and moving the data into my excel sheet.

Previously QHarr mentioned grabbing the parent element by its classname using a css class selector.

I therefore used this code:

```
 Sub Test_new_method()



Dim ie As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer

Set ie = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
        
With ie
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate2 "https://www.legalandgeneral.com/investments/funds/prices-and-reports/daily-fund-prices/"
        While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend 
        With .document
    
            .querySelector(".tabs > div:nth-child(5)").Click '
        End With
        Do While ie.Busy
        
            Loop
        While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend
        ie.ExecWB 17, 0 '// SelectAll
        ie.ExecWB 12, 2 '// Copy selection
        
        Sheets("Data_Dump").Select
        Range("A1").Select
        
        ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Format:="Text", link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False
        
    End With
    
    Stop
End Sub
```

However, while not crashing, it also doesn't change the active tab.
I have changed the nth-child to different numbers but nothing changes on the webpage.

I have 'inspected' the element, and the parent seems to be called "tabs", but the layout of this in DOM explorer is slightly different from my previous query:
[StackOverflow previous question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59395660/excel-vba-click-website-button-with-no-name-or-id-that-uses-json)

Here is a DOM extract, if helpful:

```
<div class="tabs ui-tabs ui-corner-all ui-widget ui-widget-content">
    <ul class="tabs-nav-desktop ui-tabs-nav ui-corner-all ui-helper-reset ui-helper-clearfix ui-widget-header" role="tablist">
        <li tabindex="-1" class="ui-tabs-tab ui-corner-top ui-state-default ui-tab" role="tab" aria-expanded="false" aria-selected="false" aria-controls="tabs--72484" aria-labelledby="ui-id-11">
          <a tabindex="-1" class="ui-tabs-anchor" id="ui-id-11" role="presentation" href="#tabs--72484">Index funds</a>
        </li>
        <li tabindex="-1" class="ui-tabs-tab ui-corner-top ui-state-default ui-tab ui-state-hover" role="tab" aria-expanded="false" aria-selected="false" aria-controls="tabs--72485" aria-labelledby="ui-id-12">
          <a tabindex="-1" class="ui-tabs-anchor" id="ui-id-12" role="presentation" href="#tabs--72485">Actively managed</a>
        </li>
        <li tabindex="-1" class="ui-tabs-tab ui-corner-top ui-state-default ui-tab" role="tab" aria-expanded="false" aria-selected="false" aria-controls="tabs--72486" aria-labelledby="ui-id-13">
          <a tabindex="-1" class="ui-tabs-anchor" id="ui-id-13" role="presentation" href="#tabs--72486">Fixed Income</a>
        </li>
        <li tabindex="-1" class="ui-tabs-tab ui-corner-top ui-state-default ui-tab" role="tab" aria-expanded="false" aria-selected="false" aria-controls="tabs--72487" aria-labelledby="ui-id-14">
          <a tabindex="-1" class="ui-tabs-anchor" id="ui-id-14" role="presentation" href="#tabs--72487">Multi-asset</a>
        </li>
        <li tabindex="0" class="ui-tabs-tab ui-corner-top ui-state-default ui-tab ui-tabs-active ui-state-active" role="tab" aria-expanded="true" aria-selected="true" aria-controls="tabs--72482" aria-labelledby="ui-id-15">
          <a tabindex="-1" class="ui-tabs-anchor" id="ui-id-15" role="presentation" href="#tabs--72482">N Unit prices</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
<div class="tabs-accordion mobile-only hide-expand-all" role="tablist">
  <div class="outer-panel wysiwyg ui-tabs-panel ui-corner-bottom ui-widget-content" id="tabs--72484" role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="ui-id-11" style="display: none;">
    <div tabindex="0" class="trigger" id="accordion-trigger--72484" role="tab" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="accordion-panel--72484" data-id="-72484">
      <h2 class="title">Index funds</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="panel" id="accordion-panel--72484" role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="accordion-trigger--72484">
      <p><iframe width="900" height="3100" src="https://widgets-lgim.huguenots.co.uk/Consumer-unit-trust-prices-index-tracking-funds" scrolling="no" style="border: 0px currentColor; border-image: none;"></iframe></p>
      
    </div>
  </div>
</div><div class="tabs-accordion mobile-only hide-expand-all" role="tablist">
  <div class="outer-panel wysiwyg ui-tabs-panel ui-corner-bottom ui-widget-content" id="tabs--72485" role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="ui-id-12" style="display: none;">
    <div tabindex="0" class="trigger" id="accordion-trigger--72485" role="tab" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="accordion-panel--72485" data-id="-72485">
      <h2 class="title">Actively managed</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="panel" id="accordion-panel--72485" role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="accordion-trigger--72485">
      <p><iframe width="900" height="1900" src="https://widgets-lgim.huguenots.co.uk/Consumer-unit-trust-prices-actively-managed-funds" scrolling="no" style="border: 0px currentColor; border-image: none;"></iframe></p>
      
    </div>
  </div>
</div><div class="tabs-accordion mobile-only hide-expand-all" role="tablist">
  <div class="outer-panel wysiwyg ui-tabs-panel ui-corner-bottom ui-widget-content" id="tabs--72486" role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="ui-id-13" style="display: none;">
    <div tabindex="0" class="trigger" id="accordion-trigger--72486" role="tab" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="accordion-panel--72486" data-id="-72486">
      <h2 class="title">Fixed Income</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="panel" id="accordion-panel--72486" role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="accordion-trigger--72486">
      <p><iframe width="900" height="850" src="https://widgets-lgim.huguenots.co.uk/Consumer-unit-trust-prices-fixed-income-funds" scrolling="no" style="border: 0px currentColor; border-image: none;"></iframe></p>
      
    </div>
  </div>
</div><div class="tabs-accordion mobile-only hide-expand-all" role="tablist">
  <div class="outer-panel wysiwyg ui-tabs-panel ui-corner-bottom ui-widget-content" id="tabs--72487" role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="ui-id-14" style="display: none;">
    <div tabindex="0" class="trigger" id="accordion-trigger--72487" role="tab" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="accordion-panel--72487" data-id="-72487">
      <h2 class="title">Multi-asset</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="panel" id="accordion-panel--72487" role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="accordion-trigger--72487">
      <p><iframe width="900" height="2700" src="https://widgets-lgim.huguenots.co.uk/Consumer-unit-trust-prices-multi-asset-funds" scrolling="no" style="border: 0px currentColor; border-image: none;"></iframe></p>
      
    </div>
  </div>
</div><div class="tabs-accordion mobile-only hide-expand-all" role="tablist">
  <div class="outer-panel wysiwyg ui-tabs-panel ui-corner-bottom ui-widget-content" id="tabs--72482" role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="false" aria-labelledby="ui-id-15">
    <div tabindex="0" class="trigger" id="accordion-trigger--72482" role="tab" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="accordion-panel--72482" data-id="-72482">
      <h2 class="title">N Unit prices</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="panel" id="accordion-panel--72482" role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="accordion-trigger--72482">
      <p><iframe width="900" height="1300" src="https://widgets-lgim.huguenots.co.uk/Consumer-unit-trust-prices-n-unit-trust" scrolling="no" style="border: 0px currentColor; border-image: none;"></iframe></p>
      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>  </div>
```

Does anyone have any ideas how I can select the tabs in turn?

Many thanks

Dave

Comment: Hi all, so the silence has left me to delve deeper into this, and to find out if I can work it out for myself. Well the short answer is no, but I have learned a bit about css and the Google chrome inspect tool.
I can't seem to attach an image to this, but what I have found is that the 'parent' tab is called "tabs-nav-desktop", and that it is in a ul li style.

Comment: Last year my question went to a website that had its structure in a 'div', with the parent called "table-view__tabs", so the answer to that was:
.querySelector(".table-view__tabs > div:nth-child(2)").Click 'Select tab direct

However, if I try:
.querySelector(".tabs-nav-desktop > ul li:nth-child(2)").Click 'Select tab direct
it doesn't work and crashes.
Note that .querySelector(".tabs-nav-desktop > li:nth-child(1)").Click 
doesn't crash, but also doesn't select anything.

Any ideas? Am I heading down the wrong path with this?

Regards

Dave

Comment: I've been learning more about CSS selectors, and have completed the game at https://flukeout.github.io/ 
I have also used the guid here: https://yizeng.me/2014/03/23/evaluate-and-validate-xpath-css-selectors-in-chrome-developer-tools/ which has enabled me to check my code through live on the webpage.
Using this expression in the Google chrome console: $$("#block-72483 > div > ul > li:nth-child(4)") it highlights the tab I need. I can then change the nth-child number and it highlights the other tabs.

Comment: However, I put that into my VBA:
.querySelector("#block-72483 > div > ul > li:nth-child(3)").Click 
 But while it doesn't crash, it also doesn't click the wanted tab.
Any other ideas to try?
Regards, Dave

Answer (score 0):

.querySelector("A#ui-id-1.ui-tabs-anchor").Click

This works. I tried avoiding using the ui-id as when you reduce the window size (to get the table into 'mobile' small mode, and enlarge the window once again, the id number changes. However for my purposes this is fine.

I got to this answer by using some useful Google Chrome tools:

1. SelectorGadget (offered by selectorgadget.com)
2. CSS Selector Tester (offered by Patrick Simpson)
3. And generally, the 'inspect tool' is fine for seeing things happen

And some links that QHARR and others suggested to build up my knowledge of CSS Selectors:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors

https://flukeout.github.io/

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Regards

Dave